# GCloud VM Instance, LetsEncrypt SSL - 2 Sites: One Primary Domain, One Subdomain. Why is the SSL On Subdomain Redirecting To Primary Domain?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-compute-engine

I've setup to wordpress installs within the same instance on GCloud. Without HTTPS, everything works fine - but as soon as I go to the HTTPS version of the subdomain, I'm being directed back to the primary domain.

http://dbcnextt.com/
https://dbcnextt.com/ (works fine)

http://streaming.dbcnextt.com/
https://streaming.dbcnextt.com/

Answer (score 0):

When you're making changes, use a tool like [Webconfs HTTP Header Checker](https://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php) or you can try a Chrome Incognito window because if your web browser has redirects cached and you make a change that fixes the redirects.

Instead of using just the one .htaccess file, use one for each site. dbcnextt.com is your primary domain, you can set rules for the "root" WP site in the root folder, and you'll set rules for the "subdomain" WP site in the folder where that separate WP install sits - /subdomain.dbcnextt.com/.htaccess.

Make sure your "root" WP site URL and home URL are both set to the https version. You can do this in a couple of places: in wp-admin of the "root" WP site, go to Settings > General. The "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" both need the https. If they are set to http, it will log you out when you click save. Alternatively, you can do this in phpMyAdmin - in the wp_options table, look for the 'siteurl' and 'home' options and make sure they're https rather than http.

It sounds like your "root" WP was installed when the site was insecure, running on http. Sometimes it takes more than just updating the site URL and home URL. Try using [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) which will do a search-and-replace to convert all instances of your http URLs to https URLs.

Once all that is done, if the "root" site still redirects to the non-secure version, you can install a plugin such as WordPress Force HTTPS.